# How to keep both directory and s3 bucket updated via aws-cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I want to synchronize a directory on my machine with a bucket in s3. The problem is that I find that the aws cli option of `sync` does not seem to do what I expected.

**The behavior that I'm looking for is such that when I run the command it evaluates the content of the local directory and the content of the s3 bucket and updates the one with the old content with the changes in the other.**

Can't guess the best approach. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a one way sync.  If anything is the source is new or updated then it will sync it to the destination.  Even if you may have a new file in the destination, it won't sync that down to your source.  You would need to do a sync again from destination back to source.  It's a one way sync, from source to destination.

Comment: Yeah, that is my thought, but what is the better way to achieve what I want? Sync from s3 to local dir and then otherwise? I'm not sure if that would overwrite some of the changes in the files.

Comment: I guess you can wrap it in a batch or shell script to trigger both.  Something like mys3sync src dst that will do

aws s3 sync src dst
aws s3 sync dst src

Comment: But I have just tested it and that overwrites the files if the changes are in local and the first command to be run is to download from s3 to local. I want to make sure that not data loss is produced in both directions.

Comment: Yeah that doesn't seem to be doing exactly what you're looking for, there are some extra parameters like --exact-timestamps, but you might have to write some code yourself to have more control on whether to overwrite or not.  I'm kinda surprise that aws didn't already have this option already.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with `awscli`. `aws sync s3://bucket .` will synchronize the data in both sides

If you want a tool that acts according to your needs you have to develop a python script using https://github.com/boto/boto3

Comment: That is till the moment the best approach I could find. Hope AWS implements that command in future versions.

Answer (score 1):

Npm package (and cli command) [s3-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-cli) can sync a local folder and an S3 bucket, both ways.

```
s3-cli sync [--delete-removed] /path/to/folder/ s3://bucket/key/on/s3/
s3-cli sync [--delete-removed] s3://bucket/key/on/s3/ /path/to/folder/
```

Comment: I have seen in their documentation that the invocation can be done in both ways, first the folder and then the bucket and also the other way around. Does it only `sync` in one direction when invoked or in both directions?

Comment: It syncs in one direction, but you can choose it. Maybe you can achieve what you want with two successive calls in both directions.

Comment: I'm afraid that would override the content when there are changes on both sides as it happens with the `aws-cli`. Thanks anyway.